# How to return a query from sp?

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I came across the situation where I have to return a query from sp and 
assign that to session.This sample query.Original one is large one having inner join on many table.Table name is dynamic.There 2 query in the sp.One should execute and other can send to the C# page.How to access that query in C#.I don't want it's result.just query.I have shown only one query here that I want to return.

example :

```
create Procedure Sample
(
@id int
)
as
begin
declare @pid varchar(10)
declare @query varchar(500)

set @pid = cast(@id as varchar(10))

set @query ='select * from Table1 where id = '+@pid+'' 
--Execute sp_executesql @query
--print @query
select @query
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Setting @Query Use SELECT.  This will return to c sharp page. 
Make sure not to use `ExecuteNonQuery()` method

```
SET @query ='select * from Table1 where id = '+@pid+'' 
SELECT @query AS myQuery
```

In c sharp, for example

```
DataSet ds;
YourDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
string query = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["myQuery"].ToString();
```

Comment: ya done that.But I want a C# code to access that query.I can't use datatable to access that.Because I want query not result.How to do that?

Comment: You will get your query as a string here.

Answer (score 0):

By using ExecuteScalar you can get this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Sample", con);
com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
object query = com.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an OUTPUT parameter to your stored procedure like this:

```
    @ID int , 
    @SQLQuery varchar OUTPUT
```

The later in the stored procedure code, you can set its value like:

```
    SET @SQLQuery = 'select * from users'
```

Then add this type of code in your C# to get value of this OUTPUT parameter from stored procedure:

```
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Sample", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        parm.Value = 1;
        parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parm2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SQLQuery", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        parm2.Size = 50;
        parm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // This is important!
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

        // Print the output value
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@SQLQuery"].Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I hope this will answer your question. If yes, then mark it as "answered".